# different click behaviour for same dom class

Tags: jquery

I have something like that:

```
    <div id="ajaxContentLoader">
      <a class="doSomething">do something</a>      
</div>
```

and

```
    $('a.doSomething').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        doSomething(please);            
        return false;
    });
```

now, the strange thing (for me at least) is that, if a.doSomething is OUTSIDE ajaxContentLoader it doSomething everytime it is clicked (and this is good), but, if is inside ajaxContentLoader, and its replaced with some content, and then reappended with .append(); will not work anymore (and this is bad).

what the hell?

Comment: Obligatory links to http://api.jquery.com/live/ and http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ (and yes, we've all been here ourselves).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `live` instead of `.click()`

```
$('a.doSomething').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething(please);            
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `live` instead:

```
$('a.doSomething').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething(please);            
    return false;
});
```

At the moment's you're overwriting the `a.doSomething` element which has the event handler attached. You need to reattach the event handler when the new element is added to the DOM; fortunately jQuery has the [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) function to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to make the event handler [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$('a.doSomething').live("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    doSomething(please);            
    return false;
});
```

The event handler is bound to the DOM elements. When you remove them from the DOM, the event handler is no more. When you add it back, it's a new element, and has no event handler. `live` monitors the DOM for additions matching the selector and applies the event handler to those that do. From the jQuery docs:

> Attach a handler to the event for all elements which match the current
>   selector, now and in the future.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the `live()` function to bind the click call in jQuery:

```
$('a.doSomething').live('click',function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        doSomething(please);            
        return false;
    });
```

[.live() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/live/)